# How do I vote for a moderator in the primary election?

Tags: support, user-interface, moderator-election

I've never taken part in a moderator election before. I have a candidate I want to vote for in the primary, but I don't know how.

Comment: You upvote or downvote as a normal post I think.

Comment: Just use the up-/downvote buttons?

Comment: Did you just lose the link? http://stackoverflow.com/election Keep scrolling until you reach what look something like answer posts. The link under Upcoming events takes you there too.

Answer (score 6):

Use the up- and downvote buttons, as mentioned in the sidebar:

> In the primary phase, all nominees advance to preliminary community voting. Any community member with 150 reputation may *vote* in the primary.
>
> There is no commenting in this phase, *only one up or down vote per candidate*. The candidate vote scores are all public. Initial voting should provide a rough sense of which candidates are most electable.

Answer (score 5):

On the [2016 Moderator Election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/8?tab=primary) page there are 3 tabs. The first is the nominations tab where you can read up on the individual nominations and see questions and answers from the general community. The second tab is the Primary, where you do the voting:
[image]

On this tab you use the upvote/downvote to cast your vote. You can vote for all or none or some of the nominees. There is no limit other than the number of nominees. You can only vote for each once, though you can change your vote if you decide to.

On the thrid tab will be were the voting for the Election will be. There you will vote for your top 3 choices. Make sure you cast your vote in your order of preference as that is recoreded and is how the votes are weighted. So your first vote will have more weight than your second and your second vote will have more weight than your thrid. This will all be aggregated and then the overall top 3 will win the election. I believe that the aggregate results will be posted as well for review should you want to see it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the upvote :)

Comment: @ArtOfCode No problem, though that wasn't quite what I was trying to show here :)